# Equilibrium solutions for $y'=t^{3}y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding the following. To solve the differential equation $$y'=t^{3}y$$ I go about it in the following way:
\begin{align*}
y'&=t^{3}y\\
\frac{y'}{y}&=t^{3}\\
\int\frac{y'}{y}\;dt&=\int t^{3}\;dt\\
\ln{|y|}&=\frac{t^{4}}{4}+C\\
y&=Ae^{t^{4}/4}
\end{align*}
Where $A=e^{C}$

Provided I've not made any silly errors above, I'm not seeing how $y$ can ever be constant, let alone $0$, but when I plot the slope field, I see an equilibrium solution at $y=0$. What is it that I don't understand?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Thanks to Nathan Grigg *http://slopefield.nathangrigg.net* for the following slope field.
[image: Nathan Grigg, with contributions by Clinton Curry]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your analysis. $y$ is constant when $A = 0$. It is as simple as that !

Comment: Is that allowed? I divided by $y$ to get that solution, and $A=e^{C}$, which can't be zero. I'm new to differential equations, so if there's a fancy theorem that allows me to let $A=0$ after I've assumed $y\neq0$...then that's pretty fancy.

Comment: Well, as el.Salvador wrote in his answer, it would be preferable to consider the case $y = 0$ separately. However, it turns out not to cause a genuine problem. Your solution works fine. The constant $C$ can take any value on the real axis. So take $C = -\infty$  and your new constant $A$ becomes zero.

Comment: @M.Wind, are you a physicist / physics student? :)
it turns out not to be a problem in this specific case, because you come to that conclusion after you've analyzed all the solutions properly. $C = - \infty$ is not exactly a valid constant. otherwise, what would be the mathematical meaning of $\ln |y| = t^4 / 4 + (- \infty)$?

Comment: @el.Salvador You guessed right, I am a physicist. And it is true that I care more about the validity of the final result then about mathematical strictness in the derivation. $y = A e^{t^2/4}$ is the correct solution of the differential solution, and setting $A=0$ yields the equilibrium solution. Surely you would not dispute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step of your solution, you're only able to divide $y' = t^3y$ by $y$ if you assume that $y \neq 0$. You're excluding that solution.

Comment: Wow, what a duffer. Thanks for that - cannot believe I didn't see it!

Comment: Will accept as answer in a few minutes when it lets me. Again, much appreciated.